# WSDL for Create Index Apex Class

Tags: wsdl

Could someone please, tell me how I can download just only CreateIncident wsdl in RemedyForce? There is link to download entreprise or partner wsdl but all I want is just the wsdl for the CreateIndex Apex class? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Ola.

Comment: Are you intending to invoke the reduced WSDL from Apex? If so, I have a tool that allows you to select which methods you want to generate from the WSDL. Let me know if this is the case.

Comment: @Daniel, Yes, please. Could you please, give me more information about the tool? Thank you.

Comment: Most of the details are in my [Dreamforce presentation](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/dreamforce-2014-presentation-improved.html). You can get the tool from http://www.fuseit.com/explorer. Use the WSDL2Apex tab and only check which methods you want to generate code for.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I know Fuseit.com but I will go there to look for this tool that you talked about. the wsdl is now working but how can I get it to store data into Salesforce? It is storing data into the other application. I tested it using execute anonymous. I want the wsdl/the integration to be used when an incident in created in Salesforce/RemedyForce so that the same record can be created in the other application (JTrac) and I want the record in Salesforce/RemedyForce to be updated when the record in the other application is updated. How can I accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: Is JTrac a native Salesforce application? If so, then the FuseIT tool can create Apex code to interact with the required SOAP based web services from the WSDL. If not, then you will need something else to modify the WSDL as required.

Comment: @Daniel, many thanks for your response. JTrac is an external application. However, the apex class generated from JTrac wsdl is working perfectly but because this is my first time doing this, I do not know how to go about automatically firing the apex class when an incident is created in Salesforce/RemedyForce. Passing in the parameters through anonymous windows perfectly worked. Could you please, give me a direction on how to do this? Many thanks.

Comment: ticketinformationwebservicerftojtracJtr.TicketInformationRFtoJtracPort t1 = new ticketinformationwebservicerftojtracJtr.TicketInformationRFtoJtracPort();
String clientid = 'OLA';
String incident = '00020777';
String assignto = 'jtrac@solverminds.com';
String status = 'open';
String description = 'This is a Test';
String resolution = 'This is a Test';
String notes = 'This is a Test';
String attachment = 'None';
String priority = 'LOW';
String category = 'This is a Test';
String jtracstatus = 'Open';
String duedate = '12/31/2014';
String urgency = 'LOW';
String account = 'DUBAI AGENCY';
......

Comment: ....String fixtype = 'Clarification';
String rootcause = 'EMAIL';
String result = t1.ticketInformationRFtoJtrac(clientid, incident, assignto, status, description, resolution, notes, attachment, priority, category, jtracstatus, duedate, urgency, account, fixtype, rootcause);
System.Debug(result);

Comment: Try editing you question to include your sample code. Also, based on your comments you might want to reword parts of your question to better describe the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You download the WSDL and comment out any unrelated classes / methods that you do not need.

This leaves only the methods / classes you will be using and will reduce the code you need to cover during test methods.

Unless a WSDL for the SPECIFIC method is provided this will be the only way to do it.

Comment: @Hola AKIN - Even then you'll still have the trouble of dealing with the login bits that are in the partner and enterprise WSDL.  Makes more sense to just do what Eric says here and download the enterprise and strip it down to what you need.

Comment: the wsdl is now working but how can I get it to store data into Salesforce? It is storing data into the other application. I tested it using execute anonymous. I want the wsdl/the integration to be used when an incident in created in Salesforce/RemedyForce so that the same record can be created in the other application (JTrac) and I want the record in Salesforce/RemedyForce to be updated when the record in the other application is updated. How can I accomplish this? Thanks